# CSS & Javascript, Need Hide Auto-Generated HTML By Default

Tags: javascript, html, css, perl

I am writing a free online e-book which needs a few minor formatting tweaks:

http://rperl.org/learning_rperl.html

The "Full Table Of Contents" at the very top of the page starts out by being visible for a few seconds, then finally collapses itself to be hidden.  What we need is for it to start as hidden, and not be visible at all for the several seconds while the page loads.  You can see that I have already tried to solve this issue by setting "var index_hidden=1;" at the following link, otherwise the table of contents would never hide itself at all:

https://github.com/wbraswell/rperl/blob/gh-pages/javascripts/metacpan_rperl.js#L832-L833

It probably shouldn't matter, but I'm using some custom Perl scripts to generate this file from Perl POD source, I can give more info if needed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Have "your friends at O'Reilly" really endorsed your publication and accepted the roadrunner image? Have you seen O'Reilly's [*iPhone Game Development*](http://i.booksee.org/covers/737000/3c3e04e14b48e33e8a9e112f78833b48-d.jpg) cover?

Comment: @Borodin: Sorry, I don't have time for trolls today, I've got real work to do!
Maybe next time.  ;-)

Comment: @WillBraswell: I am sure you realise that I am not trolling and I can only assume that that's a "no". The preamble to *iPhone Game Development* says **the image of a roadrunner, and related trade dress are trademarks of O'Reilly Media. Inc.** and you shouldn't be implying any relationship with O'Reilly that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Borodin: Actually, you ARE trolling.  The image of the roadrunner on the iPhone book is totally different than the RPerl roadrunner image.  We have never implied any connection between RPerl and O'Reilly, other than to promote the purchase of the O'Reilly book "Learning Perl".  If you had bothered to actually look at the images, or read the content, you would have already known both of those things.  Good luck with your next trolling opportunity, hopefully it won't have anything to do with RPerl or Perl at all.

Comment: @WillBraswell: That is a ridiculous defence, and it makes me all the more certain that you are aware of your guilt and can think of nothing better. *"We have never implied any connection between RPerl and O'Reilly"* apart from using an engraving of a creature as the frontpiece of your work, which is an established and well-known O'Reilly device; referring to the company as "our friends at O'Reilly"; referring to "Roadrunner Book and the Llama book" in the same sentence; and even copying the structure of *Learning Perl*. I may well write to the publisher and ask them about their "friend".

Comment: How does it feel, to be so full of hatred, and so devoid of actual useful advice pertaining to the technical question at hand?

Comment: And sorry, we already have our quota of jealous RPerl haters, you'll need to find some other FOSS project to pick on, we're all full up here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Although the described behavior does not appear for me (OSX + Firefox). Here's what you might do:

Hide the element by default using CSS. Add this to your `head` element (extend with stronger hiding CSS when needed).

```
<style>.wait-for-js { display: none; }</style>
```

And hide your element by adding the class

```
<div id="index-container" class="hide-index wait-for-js">
```

Last but not least, to make this trick functional. Remove the class as soon as JS is loaded, which would also mean that other logic has been loaded and you're save to show the table of contents. Be sure to load this JavaScript last thing you'll do.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('index-container').className = 'hide-index';
</script>
```

Or if you're using jQuery

```
<script>$('.wait-for-js').removeClass('wait-for-js');</script>
```

Welcome to SO!

Comment: Might I know why my answer is down voted? Does it not answer the question, is it unclear, does it endorse bad practices?

Comment: I already added one comment but it appears to have been deleted by somebody?  (I'm guessing it was done by our troll friend Borodin, but I have no proof of that whatsoever.)  Please rest assured that it was definitely not me who voted down your answer, in fact I have gone ahead and clicked the check-icon to accept your answer, although I have not yet had the time to work through all the actual Javascript stuff and try to implement it yet.  As I said in my now-delete reply, I will try your solution and let you know how it works.  Thanks again for welcoming me to Stack Overflow!  :-)

Comment: Okay I tried it out and it totally works!  Thank you so much, this was a huge help.  You can see the change is live now:
http://rperl.org/learning_rperl.html

I am also trying to shrink the size of the large empty left margin, any idea how to do that?